# How do I delete all the user's posts, using drush?

Tags: drush, comments

I frequently need to delete all comments/posts of a particular abusive user. It takes a hell of time to accomplish this with a browser. It would be great if someone could tell me how to do it using drush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run something like this via `drush php-script`:

```
<?php
global $user;
$user = user_load(1);
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {users} u ON n.uid = u.uid WHERE u.name = '%s'", 'alice');
while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  node_delete($row->nid);
}
?>
```

There's also http://drupal.org/project/user_delete.

Comment: I probably don't need to try the script, as the 'User Delete' module seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Dylan.